# ASP.NET Core AddHostedService and AddSingleton relationship

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, service

I was using AddSingleton and AddHostedService together to have a long running service (BackgroundService) in the backend while controllers accessing the same service to fetch data.
Here are what I found:

1. If both AddSingleton and AddHostedService were used, the BackgroundService would be initialized twice (not Singleton).  The controller could only access the one created in AddSingleton.

debug output (constructor called twice, see the difference in the seconds)

> **BGService constructor** service addGame:games count is 1
> **BGService constructor** service addGame:games count is 1
> ExecuteAsync 1 :games
> count is 1:[   "CONSTRUCTOR GAME AT 10/29/2021 10:37:25 AM(0)" ]
> ......
> ExecuteAsync 7 :games count is 1:[   "CONSTRUCTOR GAME AT 10/29/2021
> 10:37:25 AM(0)" ]
> service addGame:games count is 2 After AddGame: [
> "CONSTRUCTOR GAME AT 10/29/2021 10:37:24 AM(0)",   "GAME 0(1)" ]

2. If only AddSingleton was used, it worked.
3. If only AddHostedService was used, the BackgroundService was running, but DI not working in controller (Exception).

**> fail:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1](https://github.com/huangpat/CoreServiceSignalRSample)
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'CoreServiceSignalRSample.service.IBGService' while attempting to
> activate
> 'CoreServiceSignalRSample.Controllers.WeatherForecastController'.
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
> sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )**

My question is, **what is the proper way to DI a BackgroundService and why AddHostedService is recommended**?

The sample code can be found at https://github.com/huangpat/CoreServiceSignalRSample.

Startup.cs ConfigureServices

```
    services.AddSingleton<IBGService>(new BGService());
    services.AddHostedService<BGService>();
```

BGSercie.cs

```
private List<string> games;

public BGService()
{
    Console.WriteLine("BGService constructor");
    this.games = new List<string>();
    this.addGame("Constructor Game at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
}

public async Task<bool> addGame(string fGame)
{
    if (this.games.Count <= 20)
    {
        this.games.Add(fGame.ToUpper() + "(" + Convert.ToString(this.games.Count) + ")");
        Console.WriteLine("service addGame:games count is " + Convert.ToString(this.games.Count));
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        i++;
        if (games.Count == 0)
        {
            this.addGame("ExecuteAsync Game at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        JsonSerializer js = new JsonSerializer();
        
        Console.WriteLine("ExecuteAsync {1} :games count is {0}:{2}", this.games.Count, i, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.games, Formatting.Indented));

        await Task.Delay(1000 * 2 * 5);
    }
    //throw new NotImplementedException();

    /
```

/ use thread pool to start each game in collection
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every registation will create it's own type descriptor with it's own resolution rules (i.e. by default it will use corresponding constructor). You can workaround it using registration with implementation factory:

```
services.AddSingleton<BGService>();
services.AddSingleton<IBGService>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<BGService>());
services.AddHostedService<BGService>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<BGService>());
```

Comment: Wow, that is quick and it works! I can understand that it first create an instance and then reference to the same instance.  But there is more than that.  I have tried to combine lines and change orders but all failed.  It seems that AddHostedService must come after AddSingleton for DI to work.  Would you mind explain what each line is for? Thank you!

Comment: @user3670632 sorry for the delayed response. TBH looks strange, will need to investigate. But there are defientely cases when order of registration is important.